# Remove Particular Option from select Tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following combobox and I want to remove the option which value is Null (value='') by using jQuery

```
<option value=''>--Select--</option>
<option value ='1'>One</option>
<option value ='2'>two</option>
<option value ='3'>three</option>
<option value ='4'>four</option>
```

Expected combo option:

```
<select name='x' id='x'>
    <option vlaue=''>--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly as saying that you want to remove all options for which value is **not** null, then the following will work:

```
$("#x").children("option").not("[value='']").remove();
```

If it's the reverse, then:

```
$("#x").children("[value='']").remove();
```

But first you have to fix your misspellings in your code:

```
<select name='x' id='x'>
    <option value=''>--Select--</option>
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3'>three</option>
    <option value='4'>four</option>
</select>
```

Note that `value` and `/select` were misspelled in your example, and that'll keep any code from working.

Comment: You can see this working (removing everything but `--Select--`) here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLTPf/1/